# Doctrine2 how to deal with updating entities after rollback? ("The EntityManager is closed")

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am trying to do some processing within a transaction and save information about potential failure, much like this:

```
$conn->beginTransaction();
try
{
    $report = $reportRepository->find($id);
    $user = $report->getUser();

    $specification = new Specification();
    $entityManager->persist($specification);

    throw new ProcessingWentWrongException();

    $entityManager->flush();
    $conn->commit();
}
catch(ProcessingWentWrongException $e)
{
    $conn->rollback();

    // Store error info:
    $report->setState('error');
    $entityManager->persist($report);
    $entityManager->flush(); // all hell breaks loose in here
}
```

This looks like a really common pattern, but Doctrine makes it really hard to do it:

1. `flush` in the `catch{}` section will try to persist both the `$report` and `$specification` object which obviously is wrong, so I could `clear` the `entityManager`, but then...
2. If I `clear` the `entityManager`, `$report` is no longer managed by it, so I need to call `$em->merge($report)` to make it managed again. Obviously `$user` will stay unmanaged so doctrine will either perform an `insert` or complain about `persist cascade`. So I can either `merge()` the whole graph (which sucks) or `close` the entityManager, but then...
3. If I `close` the `entityManager` I can only re-retrieve the `report` instance via `$repo->find($id);` - but I don't want to do that, it's stupid.

Did I miss anything? Is there some other way to achieve the result above? I feel like Doctrine makes easy things hard.

Comment: not a real solution but I guess calling `flush()` after each `persist()` would help, at least as long as there is no exception thrown by `persist()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Short answer

Use two entitymanagers. One for the potentially unsafe operations and one for logging/reporting on the other.

#### Long answer

Generally, you cannot make sure that errors don't happen (some errors don't happen before you flush to the database). And once they happen, the entitymanager is closed for business.

Here's what I do (excerpts from config.yml):

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        default_entity_manager: 'default'
        entity_managers:
            default:
                mappings: { ... }
            logging:
                mappings: { ... }
```

For normal operations, I use the default entity manager, which requires no change to your code.

For meta-operations (like logging the progress or result of a batched import or something similar), I explicitly fetch the `'logging'` manager and use it for creating/updating the logging/report entities (and only for those).

Comment: I went for re-retrieving object since using another entity manager still leaves the problem of unmanaged relations graph, but I think my solution sucks, any other ideas? :)

Comment: Ah, I see I didn't understand your question fully, then. If your problem is that you're clearing/detaching too many entities, how about making a strategy that only detaches the problematic entity(-ies) (which you can attach to the exception so they can be handled in the catch block)? Or - how do you identify the objects you want to detach in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

In this particular example you are adding specification to `Report`. So can you this this?

```
$entityManager->clear("Your\Bundle\Entity\Specification");
```

and then do as you proposed:

```
// Store error info:
$report->setState('error');
$entityManager->persist($report);
$entityManager->flush(); // all hell breaks loose in here
```

Also, I think doing `persist` on object with assigned ID is invalid. ( `$report` object in `catch` branch)

Comment: Thanks! That's just a simplified example, I have 30 different relations defined, each of them has some relations of it's own - so I am searching for more general solution.

Comment: Ah and `persist` on an object with assigned ID is valid at least in v2.3.4 - Doctrine will perform an update or insert depending on whether object is managed by EntityManager or not

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that. I have been searching for more general solution myself few months ago - ended up in normalizing entities to `array` and pumping it into `MongoDB` server. The whole idea was to log what have changed and who did that. Now, I didn't try covering flush failures...

Comment: Calling `$entityManager->clear()` without arguments will detach all entities. See [the source](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.5/source-class-Doctrine.ORM.EntityManager.html#536) for details.